# Nodejs Expressjs Mongodb Javascript Unit Test Using Mocha Chai Sinon for random Nodejs Project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Can somebody show me how to do "**unit test**" for this sample project for function homeDog?
i have following sample function that from random project that i wish to try add unit test for it while i learn how to do unit test using Mocha Chai Sinon the sample random Nodejs Project that referencing is from https://github.com/seanaharrison/node-express-mongodb-example.

I was struggling to make a unit test for homeDog function, but then i face issues and can somebody kindly show me a working unit test on how to make a unit test for function homeDog for me to have a starting point?

And here is what i tried but failed.

[image: what_i_had_done_but_failed]

```
exports.homeDog = function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.collection('dogs');
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, dogsArray) {
        if (dogsArray) {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Dogs',
                path: req.path,
                dogs: dogsArray
            });
        }
        else {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'No Dogs Found'
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need a "mock database" but you don't use it in your code (I think) I'll try to explain how to test an API project with a `mock database`.

That is: You don't need a real DB to test your API, you need an "in-memory DB" created and closed in every execution of your tests.

First of all is install a mock dependency like [mongo-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-mock), [mongodb-memory-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-memory-server) or whatever you want.

Personally, I use `mongodb-memory-server`.

So following the docs you can set up your project. I have my `mockDB.js` file at the same level as `test.js`.

`mockDB.js`file should include something like this (this code can change if you use another package.):

```js
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server');
const mongod = new MongoMemoryServer();

module.exports.connect = async () => {
    const uri = await mongod.getUri();

    const mongooseOpts = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true 
    };

    await mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOpts);
}
```

Then, you have a file where your `mock DB` will be initialized and connected.
At this point, my `mongo DB` is initialized. I'm using `mongoose` but another option is allowed to.

The controller (`homeDog` in this case I think) file doesn't matter here because you are testing the controller so the code has to be the same that will be in production.
The controller is the code to test, so it should not be modified for tests purposes.

The last file is `test.js`.
In this file, you have to import your `mockDB.js` file and start de database.

```js
const mockDB = require('./mockDB');

... 

before(async () => await mockDB.connect());
```

In this way, you can execute your tests and the controller will execute queries to `memory database`. Also, you can use your file `mockDB.js` to implement auxiliary queries.

For example, to get a specific value from a field you can create a method like

```js
module.exports.findValueById(id) => {
  //return result
}
```

And into your test file call this module:

```js
var idFound = mockDB.findValueById(id)
```

Using this you can, for example, query the database after inserting a document and check if the collection is ok. Or check if an update has been made correctly or whatever you want.

If your function is a `GET` you only need to compare the data returned by `homeDog` with the existing "mock DB".

Comment: My intention is to create a Unit Test sorry if i get you wrong by asking how to mock database. Because where i see the function all is related to mongodb. But i cant test it isolate . i was figuring how to create a unit test for homeDog function. thank for your reference for mongodb mocking .

Comment: I'll update my answer in a while adding a test case example, sorry. But `homeDog()` is an endpoint where do you use a DB connection I think. So I suppose you will need this part.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned about unit test, it means that it should be an isolated test (no real call to database). To do so, you need to include [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) to mock some functions.

Some functions to mock:

1. `db.collection`
2. `collection.find().toArray()`
3. `res.render`

```js
// include the sinon library
const sinon = require('sinon');

// include the source file that contain `homeDog` function
const src = require('./src');

describe('test', () => {
  it('returns index with title, path and dogs if dogs array exist', () => {
    const dogs = ['doggy', 'dogg2'];

    // define mock `req` parameter
    const mockReq = {
      path: 'whatever',
      db: {        
        collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), // `returnsThis` to mock chained function
        find: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        toArray: sinon.stub().callsFake(callback => {
          callback(null, dogs) // specify dogs array here
        })
      }
    };

    // define mock `res` parameter
    const mockRes = {
      render: sinon.stub(),
    }

    src.homeDog(mockReq, mockRes); // pass the mock req and mock res to homeDog

    // check whether the function is called correctly
    sinon.assert.calledWith(mockReq.db.collection, 'dogs');
    sinon.assert.calledWith(mockRes.render, 'index', { title: 'Dogs', path: 'whatever', dogs });
  })

  it('returns index with title', () => {
    const mockReq = {
      path: 'whatever',
      db: {        
        collection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        find: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        toArray: sinon.stub().callsFake(callback => {
          callback(null, null) // give null value for dog array
        })
      }
    };

    const mockRes = {
      render: sinon.stub(),
    }

    src.homeDog(mockReq, mockRes); 

    sinon.assert.calledWith(mockRes.render, 'index', { title: 'No Dogs Found' });
  })
})
```

Result

```
  test
    ✓ returns index with title, path and dogs if dogs array exist
    ✓ returns index with title


  2 passing (12ms)
```